# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when computing f1_score

Tags: python, nlp

I am a beginner of learning nlp, and I am trying to classify a dataset with `GaussianNB()` and evaluate by `f1_score`. I got this `TypeError` when calling the `f1_score` function and here is my code:

```
dev_X_train, dev_X_test, dev_y_train, dev_y_test = train_test_split(dev_X, dev_y, test_size = 0.2, random_state =0)
classifier = GaussianNB()

dev_y_train = dev_y_train.astype(numpy.int)
dev_y_test = dev_y_test.astype(numpy.int)

classifier.fit(dev_X_train, dev_y_train)
dev_y_pred = classifier.predict(dev_X_test)

dev_y_pred = dev_y_pred.astype(numpy.int)

score = f1_score(dev_y_test, dev_y_pred, pos_label=1)
print('F1 Score: %.3f' % dev_y_pred)
```

and this is what the training and testing data look like.

```
 dev_X_train:
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> len=80 
 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
dev_y_train:
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> len=80 
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 1 0 1]
dev_X_test:
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> len=20 
 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

dev_y_test:
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> len=20 [1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]

dev_y_pred:
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> len=20 [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

I have tried `.astype(numpy.int)` as others said, but it still has the same outcome. So, could you please explain why this happens and how to fix it?

here is the full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chenchiyu/Desktop/COMP90042 NLP/Project/proj.py", line 241, in <module>
    print('F1 Score: %.3f' % dev_y_pred)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Make it into a habbit of posting the full stack trace, which also shows which line of code the error happens etc. Help us help you.

Comment: added. this is my first time to ask question on stackoverflow. sorry for that

Comment: No problem Matthew, and welcome to a rather big community. I don't think even half the people read the "how-to-ask-questions" or the FAQ's, so this type of thing happens all the time. But as the error suggests it's even more paramount to give all information, because it looks like it's a simple spelling error in which variable you're trying to print (as awarrier99) suggests :) So I'm glad you added it and I wish you the best of luck with your project :) I also formatted your question a bit as code blocks have a neat formatting trick with \`code\` to make it pop out more :)

Comment: So nice of you, Torxed, the problem has been fixed. and I will learn how to organise questions as well as the code formats. thanks for you warm comment again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to format your print string with the `score` variable instead? The error is with your `print` call, not the `f1_score` call, as seen from the stack trace. You're receiving this error because you used a format specifier for a single float and you're trying to insert an entire array (`dev_y_pred`) rather than a single scalar value. Maybe you meant to do this: `print('F1 Score: %.3f' % score)`

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks for help. it is really a stupid question lol.

Comment: @MatthewChen haha no problem, these things happen